# Python Discord Bot - Get a users roles in a different server

Tags: python, bots, discord, roles, dm

So I can check a user's roles in a server with the following code:

```py
        #Check Admin:
        playerRoles = []
        for x in message.author.roles:
            playerRoles.append(str(x))
        if "Admin" in playerRoles:
```

But I want bot to be able to detect the roles they have in a *different server than where the command was issued*. I want the command to be able to be issued by DMing it to the bot, so obviously I can't use **message.author.roles** because the user doesn't have roles in DMs, he has the role in the server.

Here's what I tried:

```py
        #Check Roles:
        playerRoles = []
        #target the user manually to get his roles in the event of a DM
        pepeServer = client.get_guild(guildID)
        targetUser = discord.utils.get(pepeServer.members, id=userID)
        for x in targetUser.roles:
            playerRoles.append(str(x))
```

This returns an error on the line  "for x in targetUser.roles:"

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'

I guess the "targetUser" it's obtaining isn't the kind with roles. Feelsbadman. How do I get the user's roles in the server from a command issued in DMs?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'` means that `targetUser` is `None`.

So your `discord.utils.get(pepeServer.members, id=userID)` doesnt return anything.

Check the server and user id.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid for not realizing xD userID was a string and not an integer. First time doing this so I had just assumed my method was wrong. Thanks for your help